# Cannot enable line wrap for raw cells in jupyter lab 4.0.8

Tags: jupyter

I have been unable to enable line wrap for raw cells in jupyter lab, version 4.0.8.

Previous solutions with jupyter config have not been successful (addition of {
"codeCellConfig": {
"lineWrap": true
}
} into the nbconfig folder as the folder did not exist). Creating nbconfig folder in jupyter config directory and adding of the above json file was also not successful.  Additionally previous solution that used "useroverrides" was not successful, as useroverrides not availables from setttings menu. Simply choosing line wrap from settings meny did not enable line wrap for coded cells. Has anyone had success in resolving this issue with a more recent jupyter lab installation? Is there something extremelly obvious that I am missing.

Comment: Did you try setting this from the User Preferences / Advanced Settings interface when within JupyterLab and did that work? Try some of the different syntax listed [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6374#issuecomment-739419610)?

Comment: Thank you so much, that thread worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

OP indicates the thread in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77488281/cannot-enable-line-wrap-for-raw-cells-in-jupyter-lab-4-0-8?noredirect=1#comment136609573_77488281) helped solve this.
Here is the particular comment:

> "Did you try setting this from the User Preferences / Advanced Settings interface when within JupyterLab and did that work? Try some of the different syntax listed [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6374#issuecomment-739419610)? "